# Should data be stored with user.config?

Tags: c#, configuration

I am able to locate user.config with:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
string path = config.FilePath;
```

I would like to store some application data in the same directory.

1. Is it good practice to do so? Or are there better standards for location to store data?
2. Should I simply use `config.FilePath.Replace("user.config", "")` to get the path to the directory? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Have you looked into [.NET Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @BJMyers According to the Application Settings Overview page, the settings are read at run time. However, it'd really make more sense for my data to be loaded upon request, as opposed to immediately immediately at runtime. Please advise if I am nonetheless able to accomplish this with Application Settings.